# Extracting data from key-value pairs to column headlines in Google Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Thanks to [Mikhail's help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64948819/split-key-value-pairs-to-columns-in-google-bigquery), I was able to extract key-value pairs from a string in my ecom data.

But now I have a slightly different problem for another report, which I am not able to solve.

**Input:**

```
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| order_id | line_items                                                    |
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| 123      | id:1|qy:1|sum:1.00|name:papaya;id:2|qy:6|sum:4.50|name:apple; |
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| 456      | id:1|qy:3|sum:3.00|name:papaya;id:2|qy:1|sum:0.75|name:apple; |
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

- The amount of purchases per row in column *line_items* is arbitrary (separated via ";") and there is much more information than only *id*, *quantity*, *sum* and *name*.
  But right now I need to only pull those (might change, but I
  think/hope I will manage that, once I understand how it's done).
- The products might increase over time. But I guess, when the respective search string (let's say I have to add "cherry" in the future) isn't found, that won't matter (will just output *null*) and I can just update the query once I have more products.

**Desired Output:**

```
+----------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+
| order_id | qy_Papaya | sum_Papaya | qy_Apple | sum_Apple |
+----------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+
| 123      | 1         | 1.00       | 6        | 4.50      |
+----------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+
| 456      | 3         | 3.00       | 1        | 0.75      |
+----------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+
```

I've tried a lot to build up on the [solution from Mikhail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64948819/split-key-value-pairs-to-columns-in-google-bigquery), but I wasn't able to bring the name value to the column headline.

It would be absolutely great, if someone pointed me into the right direction again.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
with temp as ( - temp CTE is exact solution from answer you referenced in your question
  select order_id, 
    ( select split(kv, ':')[offset(1)] from x.kvs kv where split(kv, ':')[offset(0)] = 'name') name,
    ( select split(kv, ':')[offset(1)] from x.kvs kv where split(kv, ':')[offset(0)] = 'qy') qy,
    ( select split(kv, ':')[offset(1)] from x.kvs kv where split(kv, ':')[offset(0)] = 'sum') sum
  from `project.dataset.table`,
  unnest(split(trim(line_items, ';'), ';')) items,
  unnest([struct(split(items,'|') as kvs)]) x
)
select order_id, 
  max(if(name = 'papaya', qy, '')) as qy_papaya,  
  max(if(name = 'papaya', sum, '')) as sum_papaya,  
  max(if(name = 'apple', qy, '')) as qy_apple,  
  max(if(name = 'apple', sum, '')) as sum_apple  
from temp
group by order_id
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Comment: This worked absolutely perfectly again. Thanks a lot again, Mikhail.