# Write SQL code in BigQuery to get the data in format attribute1:attribute_value1;attribute2:attribute_value2

Tags: google-bigquery, data-analysis, dataformat

I am working on the first party data. Each line in the data file for first-party data must contain all the data for a given user and should be delimited using the CARET (^) character.
The file needs to be UTF-8 encoding (or us-ascii)
Each line in the data file should contain 2 columns:

1. The first column represents the first-party User ID and must match the client first-party User ID that is used in the user matching process described in section 2
2. The second column contains all the data associated with the user and should be in the following format:
   attribute1:attribute_value1;attribute2:attribute_value2

For example, if there are 3 columns called Age Group, Gender, and Interest in the client’s registration database that need to be imported into Audience Studio, then the following represents a valid data file that can be ingested by Audience Studio:

User1234^gender:male;age:18-24;interest:fishing
User2345^gender:female

I have uploaded the csv file in the table in the bigQuery, But i am not able to perform the column formatting using SQL. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to split your columns into `user_id` and `attributes` columns which can simply be done with the `split` function. Then you have a few options, here is the simplest one maybe:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(attributes, "gender:(.*?)(?:;|$)") AS gender,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(attributes, "age:(.*?)(?:;|$)") AS age,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(attributes, "interest:(.*?)(?:;|$)") AS interest,
FROM (
    SELECT
        SPLIT(rawline, "^")[OFFSET(0)] AS user_id,
        SPLIT(rawline, "^")[OFFSET(1)] AS attributes,
    FROM 
        `yourdataset.yourtable`
)
```

You can also take inspiration from [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64949078/15062605) by @Mikhail_Berlyant.